# Is it possible to send a message from a WPF app that is hosting a CefSharp control, to the web app running in CefSharp like WebView2 can do

Tags: wpf, cefsharp, webview2

With WebVeiw2 you can send a message to a web app running in it using WebView2Ctrl?.CoreWebView2?.PostWebMessageAsJson(message).
Is there a way of doing this in CefSharp

Comment: There are a few ways of communicating from your .Net app to the browser, simply executing JavaScript, using an IJavascriptCallback. Can you provide a little more detail on your use case? Nedd to know more before I can suggest which approach is likely to fit best with your requirements.

Comment: As a general reference https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#table-of-contents

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class (I used JavascriptCallbackMessenger) to Set and Run the callbacks.

```
    public class JavascriptCallbackMessenger
    {
        private IJavascriptCallback _callback;
    
        public void SetCallBack(IJavascriptCallback callback)
        {
            _callback = callback;
        }
    
        public void RunCallback(string message)
        {
            if (_callback != null && _callback.CanExecute)
            {
                _callback.ExecuteAsync(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Create an instance of JavascriptCallbackMessenger and register it with the CefSharp control

```
CefSharpCtrl.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register(JavascriptCallbackMessengerName, _messenger, true, BindingOptions.DefaultBinder);
```

3. Set the callback in Javascript as follows (I'm not a JS developer, but this was my solution).

```
(async function() {
    const cefSharp = (window as any).CefSharp;
    
        await cefSharp.BindObjectAsync(JavascriptCallbackMessengerName);
    
        window.javascriptCallbackMessenger.setCallBack(function(message: string) 
        {
            console.log("messageHandler: " + message);
        })
    })();
```

I was using typescript, so I had to extend the Window with the newly created variable.

```
declare global {
  interface Window { javascriptCallbackMessenger: any; }
}
```

Apologies, but the formatting seems to be a bit "off"!

Comment: You can use CefSharp.PostMessage in JavaScript and avoid registering a class if all you are doing is passing a callback. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#13-how-do-you-handle-a-javascript-event-in-c

Comment: Also EvaluateScriptAsync can return a IJavascriptCallback, so you can execute some JavaScript from your .Net application to get a reference to a JavaScript function. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#2-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-that-returns-a-result in the last example captures a button click, same can be used for a basic function.